# Error when opening Cordova Project in VS2013

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, apache-cordova

Am Getting below error when i trying to open cordova project.Can anyone help me to solve my problem.

```html
C:\Documents\myproject.jsproj : 
error  : The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.TypeScript.MDA.targets" 
was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
  C:\Documents\myproject.jsproj
```

Comment: Why the Azure tag?  This has nothing to do with Azure.

Comment: I downloaded cordova todo project from azure app services thats why i tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message, this project is targeting `VisualStudio\v14.0`, which is possessed by VS2015. But you are currently using VS2013, So you are getting this error.

The best solution is to migrate to VS2015.

If you really want this project to run on VS2013, you can try create a new blank Cordova Project using VS2013 and migrate the souce codes from your existing project to the blank Project.

There is a document that might help: [Migrate a Visual Studio 2013 project to Visual Studio 2015](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/migrate-to-vs2015/).